# Patching vulnerabilities in Ubuntu LTS releases

Tags: lts, support, vulnerability

Ubuntu LTS releases have an EOL date of 5 years after release. It does not seem  packages are upgraded to newer versions.

Does this mean that packages are patched for CVEs for 5 years?

Where are the patches for these packages sourced from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages are patched. Patches are taken mostly from upstream, sometimes they are made by Canonical.

Almost every week, sometimes more frequently Ubuntu gets security updates for some packages.

Comment: https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/

These are the Ubuntu security notices that have the patches.